# Does Postgres' JDBC driver cache getAutoCommit()?

Tags: java, database, jdbc, glassfish-3, jdbc-postgres

Does Postgres' JDBC driver cache the results of `getAutoCommit()`?

Per [Glassfish 3's docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1750/6nmnbjlfi/index.html), I need to know this to determine if I can use `auto-commit` as my `connection-validation-method` (versus something else like `table` and having to pick a table):

> Because many JDBC drivers cache the results of auto-commit and
>   meta-data calls, they do not always provide reliable validations.
>   Check with the driver vendor to determine whether these calls are
>   cached or not.

I'm currently using `postgresql-9.1-903.jdbc4.jar`.

Comment: See http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/200401140906.19042.dev@archonet.com